# List of annotations in JUnit

Tags: java, junit4

Recently, I have studied and implemented the JUnit framework. As a result i am aware of few annotations which are used in JUnit :- `@Test`, `@Before`, `@After`, `@Ignore`, `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass`, `@Runwith(Suite.class)`, `@SuiteClasses({})`, `@Parameters`, `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` and `@Rule`.

I am sure there are more annotations which are used in JUnit. Can anybody guide me with a list of more annotations that can be used and under what circumstances they are used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 56):

This Github search (`@interface`) gives you the list of all the annotations :

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/search?q=%22%40interface%22&type=Code

#### Basic Annotations

[`@Test`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Test.java)
[`@Before`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Before.java)
[`@After`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/After.java)
[`@AfterClass`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/AfterClass.java)
[`@BeforeClass`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/BeforeClass.java)
[`@Ignore`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Ignore.java)
[`@Runwith`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/RunWith.java)

#### Parameterized Tests

For Parameterized tests use `@Parameters` and `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`
https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests

#### Category

[`@Category`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/categories/Category.java)
Grouping tests into categories. e.g. Fast, Slow etc.

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories

[`@IncludeCategory`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.java#L84)
Runs only the classes and methods that are
annotated with either the category given with the `@IncludeCategory`
annotation, or a subtype of that category.

[`@ExcludeCategory`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.java#L99)
Inverse of `@IncludeCategory`

#### Rules

[`@Rule`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Rule.java)
Rules allow very flexible addition or redefinition of the behavior of each test method in a test class. e.g. Creating a Temp Folder rule for creating a temp folder while running tests.

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules

#### Theory and related annotations

[`@Theory`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/theories/Theory.java)
Theories give more flexible and expressive assertions

https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Theories

[`@DataPoint`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/theories/DataPoint.java)
Annotating an field or method with `@DataPoint` will cause the field value
or the value returned by the method to be used as a potential parameter for
theories in that class

[`@DataPoints`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/theories/DataPoints.java)

Extension of `@Datapoint`
Annotating an array or iterable-typed field or method with `@DataPoints`
will cause the values in the array or iterable given to be used as potential
parameters for theories in that class

[`@FromDataPoints`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/theories/FromDataPoints.java)

Annotating a parameter of a `@Theory` method with `@FromDataPoints` will limit the
datapoints considered as potential values for that parameter to just the
`@DataPoints` with the given name

[`@ParametersSuppliedBy`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/theories/ParametersSuppliedBy.java)
Annotating a `@Theory` method parameter with `@ParametersSuppliedBy` causes it to be supplied with
values from the named `ParameterSupplier` when run as a theory

[`@TestedOn`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/theories/suppliers/TestedOn.java)

The `@TestedOn` annotation takes an array of values to be used as data points for the annotated
parameter.

e.g.

```
@Theory
public void multiplyIsInverseOfDivideWithInlineDataPoints(
        @TestedOn(ints = {0, 5, 10}) int amount,
        @TestedOn(ints = {0, 1, 2}) int m
) {
    assumeThat(m, not(0));
    assertThat(new Dollar(amount).times(m).divideBy(m).getAmount(), is(amount));
}
```