# creating user defined function for selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, user-defined-functions

I want to create some user defined functions for my webdriver automation code. I tried it, but resulted in failure.

the following is my code

```java
public class snapdeal {

    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    @Test
    public void test() {

             // I want open browser in function 1
        driver.get("http://amazon.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

            // Function 2 for searching     
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='nav_cat_2'")).click();       
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("Shoes");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='nav-submit-input']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal' and contains(text(), \"Fbt Men's 8876 Casual Shoes\")]")).click();
               }
         }
```

How ca i write two functions inside the class?

Comment: Please include the error or full exception stacktrace in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably trying to nest methods inside **test()** . [It is not possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2634827/4193730)

You can use this code below which calls the respective methods in the **test()**. It works as expected:

```
public class snapdeal {

    static WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //Method1 for Opening Browser.
        openBrowser();
        // Method2 for searching     
        searchElement();
    }

    public static void openBrowser(){
        driver.get("http://amazon.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void searchElement(){

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='nav_cat_2']")).click(); 

        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("Shoes");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='nav-submit-input']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal' and contains(text(), \"Fbt Men's 8876 Casual Shoes\")]")).click();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Anirudh: The only thing missing above are the imports, which of course can be added easily while working with an IDE. I assure you, the code works fine when run and this is no case of sock-puppeting. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is like a Hello World for Selenium for you, you could make use defined methods in Java using Junit with the following annotations which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760881/list-of-annotations-in-junit)

But as per norms we usually have a [@Before](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Before.html) method in [Junit](http://junit.org/) or [@BeforeTest](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/BeforeTest.html) method in [testng](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) for setting up the webdriver and the url of AUT, also in your code a couple of xpaths were wrong which were causing the error, Please find below the correct working code with comments:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class snapdeal {

    public WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUP()
    {
        // I want open browser in function 1
        driver= new SafariDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://amazon.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {



        // Function 2 for searching     
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='nav_cat_2")).click(); //element not needed      
        driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("Shoes");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='nav-submit-input']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title=\"Fbt Men's 8876 Casual Shoes\"]//h2")).click();
    }
}
```

The above code works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Creating user defined function have two different scope

1) Create function with piece of code and call that function whenever u needed it (Which is done above)

2) Second one creating a custom function wrt each controls like edit boxes , radiobutton , check boxes - etc , so by creating this functions u can make better feasible of your automation framework